# sql remove rows contain 'test' but keep rows contain 'contest'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like

I want to remove all campaign containing the word 'test' in their campaign names but keep the campaigns that have 'contest' in their names. Some campaigns don't have either test or contest in their names and i'd like to keep them as well.
How can I achieve this in sql in Snowflake environment? Since upper/lower case can be completely random I'm thinking of using `NAME (ilike any('%_test_%', '%_test%', 'test_%', 'test'))` however when I do this 'contest' is also removed which is not the result I want.

sample data:

```
|                    Name                      |
|AuroraEnterprisesInc_AuroraSepTestCampaign    |
|_TEST                                         |
|test                                          |
|001_test_XP_GutterDoctor_June-OctoberCampaign|
|FR_TEST_                                      |
|002_XP_HunterKnifton_21ElectionContestCampaign|
|001_XP_Kijiji_BuyandSell                      |
```

the result should be

```
|                    Name                      |
|002_XP_HunterKnifton_21ElectionContestCampaign|
|001_XP_Kijiji_BuyandSell                      |
```

Comment: I am not familiar with snowflake, but in most SQL dialects, '_' means "any character" when used with like. This would make your list very redundant.

Comment: sure, I can clean up the list. However it doesn't solve the main issue I'm trying to tackle

Comment: You sample data doesn't look complete. Is there an id column thats map to multiple rows of campaign names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to exclude all records where the NAME column contains the substring "test" unless that substring is specifically part of the larger string "contest".

In other words, you're not trying to *only* exclude the stand-alone word "test", but any record that contains "test" not preceded by "con". E.g., you want to exclude `SeptTestCampaign` and `testament` but retain `SeptContestCampaign` or `contestament`.

Assuming that's correct, a WHERE clause such as:

```sql
 SELECT ...
 WHERE ((name ILIKE '%contest%') OR (NOT (name ILIKE '%test%')))
```

should suffice. (I've added parens just to make the logical grouping unambiguous but most or maybe all of those are technically optional.)

The first criterion (`name ILIKE '%contest%'`) yields the set of records that expressly include the substring "contest".

The second (`NOT name ILIKE '%test%'`) yields the set of all records that do not contain the substring "test" at all.

The `OR` operator yields the union of those two sets.

Or if you want to delete the test records rather than just filtering them out of a result set, reverse the conditions:

```sql
 DELETE FROM my_table 
 WHERE (name ILIKE '%test%') AND (NOT (name ILIKE '%contest%'))
```

One small caveat: if a record contains *both* `contest` and (independently) `test`, the logic above will include that record in the final results. E.g., a record with the NAME `Test_ElectionContestCampaign` *will* be included in the select (and will not be removed by the delete). Based on your context I assume that's unlikely enough to be OK, but if you literally want to exclude all records that contain any instance of the substring `test` without a leading `con` please clarify.

Comment: Why "OR" in the first statement instead of "AND"?

Comment: My first case is a SELECT - retrieving the records we want rather than deleting the ones we don't as the OP asked about. (Honestly that's because I misinterpreted  the question initially.) So specifically if we want to exclude all the test records we need all the records that contain 'contest' OR don't contain 'test' at all, such that only the records that contain 'test' (not 'contest') are excluded. The DELETE example is what the OP was actually looking for, which is essentially the opposite of the WHERE conditions used in the SELECT case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression in your where clause to filter these rows:

```
select * from T1 where
regexp_instr(NAME, '\\btest\\b|_test_|\\btest_|_test\\b', 1, 1, 0, 'i') = 0;
```

| NAME |
| --- |
| 002_XP_HunterKnifton_21ElectionContestCampaign |
| 001_XP_Kijiji_BuyandSell |

Comment: Just a minor point of clarification: I believe regexp_instr is an Oracle-specific extension function but most modern SQL databases provide similar support for regexp-based where criteria, like `dbo.RegexMatch` in SQL Server or `REGEXP_MATCHES` (or the `~` operator) in Postgres. There is a SQL-standard `SIMILAR TO` operator for matching regular expressions (beyond `LIKE`)  but it doesn't support full POSIX regexp features like `\b`. There's probably a POSIX-style regexp match for your database, but `regexp_instr` may not be it.

Comment: The question is tagged with snowflake-cloud-data-platform. This syntax works on Snowflake.